# how to redirect all users coming from all other sites when referral

Tags: php

hello im looking to show a message to users when they come on my page from different sites https sites or http can someone help me to redirect users coming from all sites example if they have referral different sites with https or http referrals, this is working only from http referrals

```
<?php 
$pos = (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'http'));
if($pos===false)
  die('<h1>Restricted access</h1>');
else
{echo '<h1>It Works</h1>';}

?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to distinguish between http and https referrals or determine the referring host itself?

Comment: im looking to show It Works message to all users coming from a https or http referal, this is the problem i have i need to show it works  to all users coming from all sites in the world if they are http or https

Comment: The code you have should be fine, you may want to use stripos so it is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to detect whether the referral URL was `http://`

```
<?php 

if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'http://')) {
  die('<h1>Restricted access</h1>');
} else {
    echo '<h1>It Works</h1>';
}

?>
```

If you just want to check whether the user clicked a link from another site to arrive at yours then you can check whether `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` exists:

You can use this to detect whether the referral URL was `http://`

```
<?php 

if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
  die('<h1>Restricted access</h1>');
} else {
    echo '<h1>It Works</h1>';
}

?>
```

Comment: this is not working for what i need this i need this to show it works only if the user comes from a referral and Restricted access if he comes blank

Comment: but with http it works good with the code i shared but i need this to work with https referrals too u understand

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer. I think I understand your question

Comment: now this is working for https but not with http :( please understand me i need this working on all 2 in the same time

Comment: Ok, I obviously don't understand your question. Perhaps you can add some examples to your question to make it clearer?

Comment: im looking to show It Works message to all users coming from a https or http referal, this is the problem i have i need to show it works to all users coming from all sites in the world if they are http or https, but when you edit this was working only for https, when i did edit it was working only for http.. u understand i need this working for all 2  i tried wih HTTP_HOST but not working

Comment: Same message for http or https referrals?

Comment: yes it works message but if they come blank show Restricted access message

Comment: OK, so my code is correct. If it isn't working then can you share some URLs so we can check?

Answer (score 0):

generally regex should be used for such kind of problem ... the below should work for your problem ...

```
if (preg_match('/http(s)?/',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    echo 'redirect now';
} else {
    echo 'stay here';
}
```

Comment: This is a simple text search, strpos or stripos is more efficient and more appropriate.